# Ayuda con scipy de python, usando sus funciones de optimización

Tags: python, optimización, scipy

Estoy empezando en la aplicación de python para resolver problemas matemáticos, científicos, etc.
Estoy tratando de entender que hace la función optimize de scipy, según lo que entiendo trata de encontrar el valor que da como resultado el valor más pequeño de la función que le pasas.
En este caso la función es (x-1) / (x * x) Por lo que entiendo, esta función vale 0 cuando x vale 1, así que debería devolverme el valor de x = 1 no? Sin embargo me devuelve 7.88860905e-31 prácticamente 0, y no entiendo por qué, o qué se supone que debería hacer esa función entonces.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def funcion(x):
    return (x - 1) / (x ** 2)

def optimize():

    from scipy import optimize
    guess = -1
    r = optimize.minimize(funcion, guess, method = "nelder-mead")
    return r.x

x = np.arange(1, 10)
y = funcion(x)

sol = optimize()

print(sol)
```

Comment: Optimize está haciendo una aproximación de la solución por el método matemático de nelder-mead, existe la posibilidad de que por eso no recibas un 0 como respuesta porqué es una **aproximación** del valor mínimo por medio de iteraciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya entendí, la función no optimiza para 0 si no para el valor mínimo que esta función alcanza, y como es en teoría menos infinito cuando x vale 0, por eso la aproximación sale cercana a 0.